# Is the expression $\int {1\over 2}E^2 \, dV$ infinite for infinite volume?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

There exist a calculation about electromagnetic mass: $$m_\mathrm{em} = \int {1\over 2}E^2 \, dV = \int\limits_{r_e}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \left( {q\over 4\pi r^2} \right)^2 4\pi r^2 \, dr = {q^2 \over 8\pi r_e}$$

Reducing $r_e$ we get infinite mass. It seems to me that the expression $\int {1\over 2}E^2 \, dV$ is infinite too for infinite volume V. Please refute or confirm.

Comment: If the integral were infinite in value (divergent) then the electric field would have infinite energy. So as a practical matter--and to make the physics sensible--we somehow 'regularize' $E$ such that it has compact support or other vanishes sufficiently quickly.

Comment: @SimonS I am out of my depth physics-wise, but mathematically I observe the integral diverges here not because the integrand fails to decay sufficiently as $r\to\infty$ but rather because of its pole at $r=0$.

Comment: No, the integral of $1/r^2$ only diverges at the lower limit, $r=0$; it converges at the upper limit, $r=\infty$.

Comment: @anon, oops I misspoke, edited. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonS No chance because the declaration of an infinity of the electric field of an electron is untouchable in physics.

Comment: @anon I'm about the first integral. Please don't look only on it (if possible).

Comment: The $r_e$ here is known as the [classical electron radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius). Its value is about $2.8179 \times 10^{-15}$m. Since it is smaller than the [Compton wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_wavelength) of electron which is about $2.4263 \times 10^{-12}$m. There is no issue that $r_e$ becomes too small. Before that, quantum mechanics will take control of the physics.

Comment: @achillehui I'm not about $r_e$. I'm asking about the first integral and does it is infinite for infinite volume.

Comment: It is finite, the integrand decay as $\frac{1}{r^2}$ and the integral converge nicely.

Comment: @achillehui To give a statement for $\int {1\over 2}E^2 \, dV$ only is not possible?

Comment: By Gauss law, the electric field $E$ associated with any localized set of charges need to falls off as least as fast as $r^{-2}$. Since the volume element is proportional to $r^2 dr$, the integrand of your integral for any localized set of charges is always $O(r^{-2})$. The assertion is not limited to electric field for a single point charge.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, I get it now.